# How can i do my url flexible in Django 1.11?

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

In my project with django I should do a site with flexible url. For instance:
`mysite.com/register/kj-1k-32-mk`

When someone write some other things after register/ I want to redirect them to my site. How can I redirect them. What should my urls.py looks like?

**urls.py**

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from olvapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^register/(?P<pk>\d+)',views.guaform,name='custform'),

]
```

When I do like above, the part after register/ can't begin with a letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the `\d+` pattern which only allows a sequence of digits. If you want a slug-like sequence, you can use:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from olvapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^register/(?P<pk>[-\w]+)',views.guaform,name='custform'),
]
```

---

> **Note**: [django-1.11](/questions/tagged/django-1.11) is [no longer supported <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) since April 2020, you should consider upgrading the Django version.